# Retrive JSON from body in a POST request - Java

Tags: java, android, json, post, restlet

I'm developing a REST server using RESTlet framework.
I'm in the process of receiving `POST` requests with a `JSON object` in the body. But I'm lost on how can I access the `JSON object` that comes in the `POST` body. So I'm asking for some direction here on how to access the body of the `POST` request.

This `POST` requests will be made by the clients using my server.

My server is running on android.

**EDIT:**

My class is extending `Restlet`, I know how to do it if it was extending `ServerResource`, but in this case I can't change from extending `Restlet` to `ServerResource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do something like this in a ServerResource:

```
@Post
public void yourMethod(Representation rep) {...}
```

Or...

If you are extending `Restlet` and overriding the `handle(Request, Response)` method or similar then you can call `getEntity()` on the request to get the `Representation`.

Comment: My class is not extending `ServerRersource` but extending `Restlet`